# Get all Latitudes and Longitudes for a company

Tags: android, ios

I am working on a mobile application, and I would like to set up a database based on latitude and longitude to inform user on the map to show closest bank.

How could I get all bank of america latitude and longitude in the United States? Any guidance?

Comment: http://locators.bankofamerica.com/locator/locator/LocatorAction.do there's a branch locator

Comment: But this requires a lot of manual work. I am looking a webservice or something else which will return me all the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Why in the world would you think there's a webservice that does that?

Comment: I thought that stores should be stored in the webservices like googlewebservices.

Comment: I really don't see the use-case for a business to have public databases of branch coordinates. If you want to do that you're probably going to have to do a lot of digging and manual work

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Google Maps places API?

https://developers.google.com/places/android/start